# Is there an existing data structure that is of fixed size, and will push the oldest/last element out if a new element is inserted?

Tags: data-structures, arrays, queues

I'm looking for a data structure that will push its oldest/last element out if a new element is inserted. For example, let `D` represent the structure. `D` contains 3 elements of the type `Number` `D`'s default values will be initialized to `1, 2` and `3`.

$$D = [1, 2, 3]$$

If a `Number` that contains the value `5` is inserted into `D`, `3` will be pushed out, while `1` and `2` are shifted right.

$$D = [5, 1, 2]$$

The first thing that comes to mind would be an array, but the definition does not include the pushing behavior.

Comment: Well there is no in-built data structure but it is simple to implement using a [Doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) linked list right?

Comment: What about using a wrapper inheriting from a queue? Then you add the method `void push_replace(T val) { pop(); push(val); }`.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi should probably be `T push_replace(T val) { T old = pop(); push(val); return old; }`

Comment: There definitely is now: you just informally defined it; perhaps you should ask if it is well-known, has a generally agreed interface and whether implementations are available (not that the last is a great issue).

Comment: @valbaca I'm thinking of C++ where `pop()` returns nothing due to problems with stack unwinding in case of exceptions copying out a complex object, so you're supposed to use `front()` before if you need it before discarding. But sure, if you don't care about exceptions your way can be better.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Fixed-size queues are often implemented using what some people call [circular buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). If you remove the protection against it being full, you get the desired behaviour.

Of course, no *actual* pushing will happen in the array -- that would be too expensive -- but it will *look* like it from the outside.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62082/discussion-on-answer-by-raphael-is-there-an-existing-data-structure-that-is-of-f).